# In what circumstances should I use instance variables instead of other variable types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, variables

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to know in what circumstances should I use instance variables instead of other variable types and if there are security reason for those.

Example:

```
# Using an instance variable
@accounts = Account.find(...)

# Using a "local"\"normal" variable
account = Account.find(...)
```

Comment: A class variable is like `@@accounts`. `@accounts` is a instance variable.

Comment: The first example you give is an instance variable, not a class variable. The second is a local variable. Are you referring specifically to controllers, models or just Ruby classes in general?

Comment: @LBg, @Pan Thomakos - Sorry, was a my mistake. I am not expert on the variable matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general an instance variable is local and persisted inside an instance of an object, whereas a local variable is only local and persisted inside a function/object/block scope. For instance:

```
class User
  def name
    @name
  end

  def name= name
    @name = name
  end
end

def greet user
  name = user.name || 'John'
  p "Hi, my name is #{name}"
end

user = User.new
greet user
=> 'Hi, my name is John'
name
=> NameError: undefined local variable or method 'name' for main:Object
user.name = "Mike"
greet user
=> 'Hi, my name is Mike'
@name
=> nil
```

In the greet function `name` is a local variable that is only defined within that function. The name variable is set on the first line on the function, `name = user.name || 'John'`, but its value is not persisted outside of the function. When you try calling `name` you get a `NameError` because name has only been defined as a local variable within the greet function.

`@name` is local to the user instance of the User class. When you try calling it outside of that context you get `nil`. This is one difference between local and instance variables, instance variables return nil if they have not been defined, whereas local non-instance variables raise an Error.

Notice that both variable types are local to a specific context though. `@name` is defined within the user instance, so when you call `user.name` you are calling the name function in the user instance, in which `@name` is defined. `name` is only defined in the greet function, so when you call `p "Hi, my name is #{name}"` you are able to get a value for `name` because you are within the scope in which it is defined.

Comment: Can you explain why you would use @name instead of simply a local variable name in your getter method? Since both instance variables and local variables are valid within their context, why make the distinction between the two?

Answer (score 13):

@Pan's answer gives a good explanation of the difference between them.

In general (in pretty much any language) you want to define variables in the smallest scope required.  So if you don't need something to be persisted across function calls, then make it local.

If you need a variable to be persisted across function calls, but only for a particular class instance, make it an instance variable.

If you need something that is shared between **every** instance of that class, then use a class variable, however the need for this should be somewhat rare, so think carefully whether you really need a class variable.

(Disclaimer: I've only played with Ruby for about 2 weeks, so this is mostly a language agnostic answer, but I'm pretty sure it applies to Ruby.  Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.)