# Rails: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) for .destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My error message is "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)"

for this line: @post = Post.destroy in my

```
PostsController#destroy
```

I have a model which is post.rb

My Posts Controller is here

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end  

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post = Post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
  end

end
```

In my view I have this code:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post),
  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

This is what it says I have for the parameters in the request

```
{"_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Pzsnxv8pt+34KIKpYqfZquDv3UpihkINGSJxomMNsW4=",
 "id"=>"3"}
```

What in the heck am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to provide the `ID` to the `destroy` method:

```
Post.destroy(params[:id])
```

As stated here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy

Comment: Ok, question though why would I even need to do the Post.find prior to that then if I just passed .destroy the :id   ?

Comment: Well, you don't need to find it. Just pass the id and destroy it.

Answer (score 4):

Precisely what the error says.

You can:

- Call `destroy` on an instance with no argument, e.g., `@post.destroy`
- On the class with an id, e.g., `Post.destroy(an_id)`

Answer (score 4):

Here is your problem:

```
@post = Post.destroy
```

In Ruby you can destroy object in this way:

```
@post.destroy
```

Another tip: when you are using variables just inside model or controller, declare them as locals by not adding @ in front of them and use @ just for variables that you need to use globally. Learn more about that here:
[In what circumstances should I use instance variables instead of other variable types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278999/in-what-circumstances-should-i-use-instance-variables-instead-of-other-variable)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you wish to write:

```
@post.destroy
```